# Two-part ML classification model on panel data - is it viable?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series

I have a dataset of medical encounters, and I aim to predict whether a patient will return to the hospital within 30 days after being discharged. Each row in my dataset corresponds to a specific encounter with a patient. It's possible for the same patient to be associated with multiple encounters.

I was planning to develop a two-part model. The first part would utilize a traditional machine learning approach, making predictions based solely on data from the individual encounter. The second part would consider the patient's history (for those who have one); in this part, I would focus on the changes in certain metrics, such as variations in glucose test results between past and recent observations. By following this methodology, I would end up with a new dataset where the first feature is the predictions from the first part of the model, supplemented with additional delta features, like glucose test results at time t and t-1. Then, I would apply a classifier, such as logistic regression, to make the final predictions about whether the patient will return to the hospital after that specific encounter, a method akin to stacking.

Does this approach seem viable? Are there alternative methods to address this task?